# Add cornerRadius to the 1st and 3td UICollectionViewCell in a 3 cells per row layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that has 3 cells per row. I need to set `topLeft` and `bottomLeft` `cornerRadius` to the left one, and `topRight` and `bottomRight` to the right one. The center one does not have `cornerRadius`.

[image: Cell looks like this]

### Extension method the sets cornerRadius

```
func setRadius(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    layer.mask = mask
}
```

I have used this code to find out which one of the cells needs to have cornerRadius.

```
    let index = indexPath.row

    if index == 0 || index % 3 == 0 {
        cell.setRadius(corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: TPSetting.cornerRadius)
    }

    else  if ( index - 2) % 3 == 0 {
        cell.setRadius(corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: TPSetting.cornerRadius)
    } else {
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    }
```

This works as expected for the first time. But when upon calling `collectionView.reloadData()`, it messes up and the center one gets also `topRight` and `bottomRight cornerRadius`.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Cells are reused. Second code doesn't seems to call first part. You might want to remove the mask, or instead of doing `cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0`, do `cell.roundCorners(cornders: [], raidus: 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cells being **reused without being deallocated** when you scroll / reload data. That's expected behaviour.

In order to "reset" introduced changes to corner radius, you can:

- Subclass cell.
- Override `prepareForReuse` method in subclass to undo changes introduced in `setRadius` method. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)
- Don't forget to call `super.prepareForReuse` inside overriden method.

Put the code inside method:

```
self.layer.mask = nil
self.layer.cornerRadius = 0
```